# How to push new WiFi credentials to Zebra printers

Tags: putty, zebra-printers, zpl

I'm struggling to get any useful answers from zebra support so I've thought I might get some help here... in our company there is over 5k of zebra printers and many of them will need wifi credentials swap, zebra support suggests using zebra setup utilities for this but this solution can do changes only on one printer at the time, is there any way to push new credentials via some script to indicated IPs at once?

zebra setup utilities generates code for specific device which looks like this:

```
^XA
^WIA
^NC2
^NPP
^KC0,0,,
^NNHostnameisThatNecessary?
^WAD,D
^WE128,1,O,H,536F6D654D84558F70,,,
^WP0,0
^WR,,,,100
^WSNewWifiSSID,I,L,,,
^NBS
^WLOFF,,
^WKOFF,,,,
^WX03,1,O,H,536F6D654D84558F70,,,
^XZ
^XA
^JUS
^XZ
! U1 setvar "wlan.country_code" "not selected"
! U1 setvar "wlan.allowed_band" "all"
! U1 do "device.reset" ""
```

is it possible to cut only credentials part to some script.txt and distribute it on RAW port via Putty or powershell somehow?

I'm not sure how much of above code can be removed, it has to be universal for various device models and not just for one hostname

Answer (score 1):

Since all the Zebra printers have the FTP protocol enabled by default, I did that using the command line of WinSCP.

First you have to create a batch file which uses the WinSCP FTP client and that recalls a text file which contains the commands required to open the FTP connection with the printer, send the file and close the FTP connection. This is the file you'll have to run once all the 3 files will be ready and in the same folder.

upload_file.bat

> ```
> winscp.com /script=ftp.txt /parameter ftp://user:password2@192.168.0.53
> winscp.com /script=ftp.txt /parameter ftp://user:password1@192.168.0.50
> pause
> ```

You can add a line for each printer you want the file to be sent to and just replace the IP address at the end of the line.

Then you've to create the FTP commands file, which is the file that opens the FTP connection with the printer, send the file (command.zpl) and closes the connection

ftp.txt

> ```
> open %1%
> mput command.zpl
> exit
> ```

Final step is to create the file (command.zpl) with the command you need to send to the printers and, in your case, you can use the script generated by zebra setup utilities.

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't changes any settings on test device

````C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP>winscp.com /script=ftp.txt /parameter ftp://usr:pwd@xx.xxx.xx.xx
Connecting to xx.xxx.xx.xx ...
Connected
Starting the session...
Session started.
Active session: [1] usr:pwd@xx.xxx.xx.xx
command.zpl               |          392 B |    0,0 KB/s | binary | 100%
````
does this 100% means it was sent successfully?

Comment: since the last command in the configuration is to reboot the printer, does the printer reboots when you send the file?

Comment: I don't understand why you had to remove the link? Please see: [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). Clearly you copied your [answer from here](https://www.thezcorner.com/printers/managing-multiple-printers/printers-send-a-file-to-multiple-printers).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I just followed the advice. Yes, that's my blog.

Comment: there was no reboot observed while sending zpl file with this method, even if there was only this line 

````! U1 do "device.reset"````

Comment: few questions that can help the troubleshooting: did you left a carriage return after the device.reset command? can you open the printer webpage by browsing the printer's IP? have you checked if the ftp is active on the printer (ip.ftp.enable) and if the ip.ftp.execute_file is on as well? can you connect via ftp from command prompt?